# Process list of files in makefile with $(notdir ...)

Tags: makefile, gnu

I would like to apply the 'notdir'-function to a list of files I obtain from a wildcard match. While '$(notdir $(wildcard dir/*.tst))' works, I do not manage to first store the list in a variable ('FILES' in the Makefile below) that then is processed by $(notdir ...). Using the variable directly  ('$(notdir $(FILES))') results in the wildcard being returned, using value ('$(notdir $(value $(FILES)))') yields an empty result.

```
.PHONY: show

FILES := dir/*.tst
FILES2 := dir/a.tst dir/b.tst
#NAMES := $(notdir $(FILES))
NAMES1 := $(notdir $(value $(FILES)))
NAMES2 := $(notdir $(FILES2))
NAMES3 := $(notdir $(wildcard dir/*.tst))

show:
    @echo "FILES: " $(FILES)
    @echo "NAMES1: " $(NAMES1)
    @echo "NAMES2: " $(NAMES2)
    @echo "NAMES3: " $(NAMES3)
```

I also tried $(notdir $(eval $$(FILES))), but this results in a "missing separator" error.

What am I missing here? I'd have expected that value would do the job...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
FILES := $(wildcard dir/*.tst)
NAMES := $(notdir ${FILES})
```

Comment: This does not work either, I get '*.tst' as result (NAMES3 is a.tst b.tst, which is what I'd like to have)

Comment: Actually, this works but the 2nd line can be simplified to `NAMES := $(notdir $(FILES))`. The problem thus was the content of `FILES` was generated.

Comment: @user52366 You are right, `notdir` can take a list indeed. Updated.